# Autowiring both the constructor and the field

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Is it wrong to autowire both the field and the constructor when doing the automatic configuration of the spring container. For example:

```
@Component
public class Test1 {

    @Autowired
    private Test2 B;

    @Autowired
      Test(Test2 C) {
      this.B=C;
    }
}
```

And could you explain what happened exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong. You may have two `Test2` beans, one named "B" and one named "C" (names should be lowercase BTW). That constructor will be called first, setting the field to `C`; after that the field will be injected, overwriting the field with `B`. If there is only one `Test2` bean then it will work, but keep in mind that the point of constructor injection is to avoid field injection and enable use of `final` fields instead.